# git log -L without diff

Tags: git, git-log

I'm trying to use `git log -L <start>,<end>:<filename>` but I would like to have very limited output (actually just hashes). While --pretty prints the commit info in the format I want, I did not find a way to not display the diff...

e.g. on linux-next what I tried is:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H" -s -L 70,70:./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h
```

where (according to the manpage) the -s is supposed to Supress the ouput of the diff, however the output is:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%H" -s -L 70,70:./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h
6abcd98ffafbff81f0bfd7ee1d129e634af13245
diff --git a/include/asm-x86/irqflags.h b/include/asm-x86/irqflags.h
--- a/include/asm-x86/irqflags.h
+++ b/include/asm-x86/irqflags.h
@@ -1,2 +64,1 @@
-#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
-# include "irqflags_32.h"
+{

96a388de5dc53a8b234b3fd41f3ae2cedc9ffd42
diff --git a/include/asm-x86/irqflags.h b/include/asm-x86/irqflags.h
--- /dev/null
+++ b/include/asm-x86/irqflags.h
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
+# include "irqflags_32.h"
```

I am using git version 2.10.2

Comment: Could you use something like this instead to get around it? 

`git blame -L70,70 ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h | cut -d ' ' -f1`

Comment: Nope, that would only give me the last commit that changed that line ... not the history. So in the above example I would only get back 6abcd98f but  not 96a388de thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Git version 2.22 and later now supports mixing `-L` with `-s`.  See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680242/1256452).

---

The `-L` option is not currently (and apparently never was) compatible with `-s` / `--no-patch`, because of [this code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/line-log.c#L973-L984) called from [`line_log_print`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/line-log.c#L1104-L1111), called from [the top of `log_tree_commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/log-tree.c#L869-L870) when `-L` is in effect.  Said code simply outputs the entire chosen line-range from any matched commit.  (You could patch the hack to obey the diff output options, perhaps.)

(The other obvious workaround would be to use `git rev-list` instead of `git log`, except that `-L` is, as that first link notes, not properly integrated in the first place, so that `git rev-list` does not handle it.)

Comment: thanks for this very precise answer... I'll just use the git log as is and egrep out the line with the commit.

Answer (score 7):

That will be clearer with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019).

"`git log -L<from>,<to>:<path>`" with "`-s`" did not suppress the patch
output as it should.
This has been corrected.

See [commit 05314ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05314efaeaa0ae7cb0aa26d6347eabfe7cd8fc43) (11 Mar 2019), and [commit 9f607cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f607cd09c4c953d76de4bd18ba1c9bf6cf383cd) (07 Mar 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 31df2c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31df2c1019733ac22fc848aa2658a0e25af70a79), 09 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `line-log`: detect unsupported formats

> If you use "`log -L`" with an output format like "`--raw`" or "`--stat`", we'll silently ignore the format and just output the normal patch.
> Let's detect and complain about this, which at least tells the user what's going on.

It will now clearly display:

```
-L does not yet support diff formats besides -p and -s
```

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), the documentation adds more.

See [commit 2be4586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2be45868a840f65ae16d171b5ae503846fa17b95), [commit 2be4586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2be45868a840f65ae16d171b5ae503846fa17b95) (26 Dec 2019) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c4117fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4117fcb97dbf5bc59d9cff09e7e4c0425fe8c27), 06 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### doc: `log`, `gitk`: document accepted line-log diff formats

> Currently the line-log functionality (`git log -L`) only supports
> displaying patch output (`-p | --patch`, its default behavior) and suppressing it
> (`-s | --no-patch`).
> A check was added in the code to that effect in [05314ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05314efaeaa0ae7cb0aa26d6347eabfe7cd8fc43)
> (`line-log`: detect unsupported formats, 2019-03-10) but the documentation was not updated.
>
> Explicitly mention:
>
> - that `-L` implies `-p`,
>   that patch output can be suppressed using `-s`,
> - and that all other diff formats are not allowed.

And:

> The line number, regex or offset parameters  and  in `git log -L <start>,<end>:<file>`, or the function name regex in `git log -L :<funcname>:<file>` must exist in the starting revision, or else the command exits with a fatal error.

So, in addition of `You can specify this option more than once`, you have:

> Implies `--patch`.
> Patch output can be suppressed using `--no-patch`, but other diff formats (namely `--raw`, `--numstat`, `--shortstat`, `--dirstat`, `--summary`, `--name-only`, `--name-status`, `--check`) are not currently implemented.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f8a1cee7b38ef3125ce69dad24af41746a0722a0/Documentation/git-log.txt#L80-L91)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt))</sup>" is documented to take no pathspec, but this was not enforced by the command line option parser, which has been corrected.

See [commit 39664cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39664cb0aca42f240468ddf84fe75df4172ab63f) (04 Nov 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f8a1cee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8a1cee7b38ef3125ce69dad24af41746a0722a0), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39664cb0aca42f240468ddf84fe75df4172ab63f): diagnose `-L` used with pathspec as an error
>
> <sup>Heled-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The `-L` option is documented to accept no pathspec, but the command line option parser has allowed the combination without checking so far.
> Ensure that there is no pathspec when the `-L` option is in effect to fix this.
>
> Incidentally, this change fixes another bug in the command line option parser, which has allowed the `-L` option used together with the `--follow` option.
> Because the latter requires exactly one path given, but the former takes no pathspec, they become mutually incompatible automatically.
> Because the `-L` option follows renames on its own, there is no reason to give `--follow` at the same time.
>
> The new tests say they may fail with "`-L` and `--follow` being incompatible" instead of "`-L` and pathspec being incompatible".
> Currently, the expected failure can come only from the latter, but this is to future-proof them, in case we decide to add code to explicitly die on `-L` and `--follow` used together.

Answer (score 1):

one grep solution is to pipe the output to grep to only print lines matching a commit:

```
git log -L 10,11:example.txt | grep 'commit \w' -A 4
```

grep matches the first line of each log entry and the prints the next 4 lines with the -A flag

It's a bit verbose though. Would love to hear if anyone has a better solution!