# git log pretty format doesn't work with line limiters

Tags: git

Hi so I think `pretty format` doesn't work with `-L<start>,<end>:<file>`

If my git command is only

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H\t%an\%s" --author=author_name file
```

then all is well. But if I add

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H\t%an\%s" --author=author_name -L100,200:file
```

then I get the `git diff` for those lines but without the pretty formatting.

Any knows of any work around? I need simple format that I can control. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. this may be related to a problem I had a few weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427590/git-log-l-without-diff
Apparently when using -L you have restricted control over the output format...

Comment: hi, what is your git version?   git --version

Comment: @andipla: thank you. That looks like my problem. So have you found out anything besides what you commented there?

Comment: @anonyXmous: mine is currently 1.9.2